# What are the actual issues with backing Selenium WebDriver with Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-rc

In the [Selenium WebDriver documention](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#backing-webdriver-with-selenium) about backing WebDriver API usage with Selenium RC it is stated:

> There are currently some major limitations with this approach, notably that findElements doesn’t work as expected. Also, because we’re using Selenium Core for the heavy lifting of driving the browser, you are limited by the JavaScript sandbox.

However, I can't find any more information on what those limitations are: does anyone know what they are or can provide further links to further information?

Answer (score 1):

This bit in the wiki in particular, is talking about how you can use the Selenium 1 commands Inside of the Selenium 2 test which is **BAD**.

To answer your question about those limitations... we need to first understand the difference between Selenium 1 and 2.

#### Selenium 1:  Executes arbitrary JavaScript against the page

This being said, it has limitations right out of the box.  For example, a click might not be caught by a javascript event since it's not actually invoking a "click" on the browser, rather, just faking a click using JS.

#### Selenium 2:  Ties directly into the browser using the WebDriver API

This being said, Selenium 2 will invoke native code, that the user would actually perform against the selected element.

So in the context of executing Selenium 1 tests inside of a Selenium 2 test... Since Selenium 1 is executing JavaScript, you aren't performing what the user would actually be doing.

Also keep in mind, the wording says "limitations with this approach".  There is no complete "list" of limitations.  In itself, it **IS** limiting because you are providing Legacy support to newer scripts.  Which, while nice to have, should never really be necessary.. Either stick to Selenium 1, or 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the point about event input is useful. I'm still looking for a bit more explanation other than "it's legacy therefore it's bad": sometimes a legacy approach is the right one to choose depending on the context of the decision and at the moment I can't make a judgement whether any of the limitations are actually issues in the context of the usage scenario I'm looking at because I don't know what they are or the dimensions of them.

Comment: @TheJuice Try it, for your specific "it", and see what happens.

Comment: and as I said, the wording is "the approach" has some limitations.  I don't think there is a list of those limitations, other than the theory